# How can I assign char pointer a value?

Tags: c

I'm doing my assignment about simulating swaping in OS and i have to run c files including code's below. It's about 8bit addressing with 4B page size.

```
char foo(void *PTBR, char va)
{
    char *entry;

    char pte_offset = (va & PFN_MASK) >> 2; /* PFM_MASK : 11111100 */

    ...

    /* page table */
    entry = (char *)PTBR + pte_offset;

    ...
 
}
```

Despite the fact that `PTBR` has a address value(e.g. 0x0000600003e00000) and `pte_offset` has a value(e.g. '\x19'), when I debug the executable file based on this source code `entry` value does not change. It just stay `""` while `foo()` ends.
I searched about the diff between char pointer and char array but that didn't help me.

I'll be so thanks about any response about this problem!!

I'm working on m1 mac, vscode.

Comment: `entry1` isn't returned anywhere in the code above. It's a local variable

Comment: The debugger typically tries to interpret the type of the variables. So for example a `char *` variable will usually be treated as a null-terminated string, and the debugger will try to show the string that it points to. If the data the pointer isn't the correct type, the debugger will show wrong data. Instead check the actual value of the variable. Doesn't the debugger tell you the actual pointer value (most will commonly show both the pointer value and the contents of the location it points to).

Comment: @phuclv I meant that 'until foo's stack frame poped'.

Comment: The question is unclear. What are the other values? Why haven't you set `pa`? If you have but it isn't relevant why did you show it? Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've checked the debugger and 'entry:""` and '*entry:'\0'` is the only thing i have and both dose not change.

Comment: Then add a watch for `(void *) entry`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx for your help I figured out by looking at pointers value!

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for by bad. I'll try to enhance my question as good as possible adopting your advice and link!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do? Add an offset to the start point address and save the char value at the computed address? Briefly you wanna do some pointer arithmetic, don't you? Since the pointer values are unsigned integer values it doesn't much different than the arithmetic operations.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PFN_MASK 0b11111100u

char foo(void *PTBR, char va)
{
    char *entry;

    int pte_offset = (va & PFN_MASK) >> 2; /* PFN_MASK : 11111100 */
    printf("start address %p, offset %d\n", PTBR, pte_offset);

    /* page table */
    entry = PTBR + pte_offset; // Pointer arithmetic
    printf("entry %p\n", entry);

    *entry = va;
    printf("entry address %p, value at that address %c\n", entry, *entry);
 
}


int main() {
    
    char charForPTBR; // This is the starting address
    
    foo(&charForPTBR, 'S');

    return 0;
}
```

Check the output out:

```
start address 0x7ffcbe7289cf, offset 20
entry 0x7ffcbe7289e3
entry address 0x7ffcbe7289e3, value at that address S
```

**Note** The above code is compiled using GCC in Linux. What compiler does the VSCode use?

Comment: Motivated by your code I printed the address value of my variables and knew that even variable is pointer it differs size due to pointing data type. Thanks for your help 